# Allowing escape to exit full screen as it normally does in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I'm enabling full screen mode in my Cocoa/Mac app, and the default behavior obviously is that you can hit the escape key to exit out of full screen mode. I've added some NSTextViews (inside NSScrollViews), and now they are intercepting the escape key and I'm unable to exit out of full screen.

What's the best way for me to still allow the escape key to exit out of full screen and not be intercepted by my NSTextViews?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default key binding for Escape is to `-cancelOperation:`. In response to that, `NSTextView` then turns around and sends itself `-complete:` to do text completion.

Is that what you're seeing when you press Escape? Does the text view offer to complete any text that you've typed?

The first thing to try is to disable completion by implementing `-textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:` in the text view's delegate and returning `nil`.

If that doesn't work, implement `-textView:doCommandBySelector:` and compare the selector to `@selector(cancelOperation:)`. If it's not equal, return `NO` to allow normal processing. If it is, try passing it up the responder chain using `[[theTextView nextResponder] doCommandBySelector:theSelector]`. Then return `YES` from your delegate method to prevent the text view from trying to handle it.

If that still doesn't work, instead of passing it up the responder chain, check if the app is in full-screen mode by testing if `[NSApp presentationOptions]` contains `NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen`. If it is, get it out of full-screen mode by setting a normal set of presentation options. Alternatively, you can test the main window to see if its style mask includes `NSFullScreenWindowMask` and, if it does, call `-toggleFullScreen:` on it. Again, you'd return `YES` from your delegate method to prevent further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ken's suggestions, here's what I ended up doing to get it to work:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    if (commandSelector == @selector(cancelOperation:)) {
        if([self inFullScreenMode]) {
            [self.window toggleFullScreen:nil];
        }
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) inFullScreenMode {
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions opts = [[NSApplication sharedApplication ] presentationOptions];
    if ( opts & NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```